# The communication object cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted

Tags: wcf

I have a sample WCF project that reproduce a problem that I have with my real WCF application.
You can download the source code of my sample WCF application [here](http://cid-199d4ba91e41eb8d.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/TestWCFLongExecution.zip)

Accoding to the timeouts sets in the code and config files, I don't understand what is appening :

```
**** Server exception : System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: 

The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings+SecurityReplySessionChannel, cannot be used for communication because it 
has been Aborted.

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfClosedOrNotOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings.ServerSecuritySessionChannel.SecureApplicationMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings.SecuritySessionRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc& rpc)

**** client exception : : System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT/Cancel' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.ProcessRequestContext(RequestContext requestContext, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.ReceiveInternal(TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.CloseOutputSession(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.CloseSession(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean& wasAborted)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\sdoucet\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestWCFLongExecution\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 25
```

Answer (score 7):

We had a similar issue because the application pool hosting the service was configured to have Maximum Worker Processes greater than 1.  For a call to Abort or Close to succeed, it needs to be routed to the same service instance that handled the original request.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I had the exact same issue in our customers staging environment.  One of their devs had set the 'Maximum Worker Processes' to 5, causing these exceptions.  We were using wsfederationhttpbinding and have a Security Token Service (STS) in place too, making the exception it was throwing even more confusing - suggesting that the token was invalid.  In fact, the request was just sometimes being directed to the wrong worker process.

Comment: We observed the same issue and we were using wshttpbinding with message security. Having Netscalar load balancers in front of the web service machines made triaging even harder. We initially thought that the LB was not maintaining sticky sessions, and tried to see if taking the LB out of the equaltion would solve the problem. But it did not and thats when we noticed the Maximum Worker Processes setting was set to more than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are passing exceptions back to the client. WCF doesn't like regular exceptions, it wants fauls or a FaultException in case of errors. After and exception has been returned the channel is in a faulted state and cannot be used again. After a FaultException the channel is still usable.

Comment: You're right, but the exception is not thrown by my code. It is thrown by the WCF infrastructure. I wan't to know why this exception is thrown and how to avoid it. I know that my service is running for 10 minutes, but according to the timeouts sets, I don't understand the exception.

Comment: The first thing to do is enable full tracing in the service. This will often give you a lot of info on what the original problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I made a wcf service async call. After receiving the result in the async_completed method I got an exception.

**"An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check InnerException for exception"**

InnerException:
**"The communication object cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted"**

After a lot of effort I find the solution, just catch the exception without throwing in the async_completed method. (i.e. implemented the try/catch). I didn't understand what is the exact problem, but somehow communication channel is breaking.

I tried the above approch from the following link

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2008/05/23/clean-up-wcf-clients--the-right-way.aspx

Still I am not confident that this is the right approach, but as per my scenario with the operation result I am not doing anything furtherly. So it is catching exception and stopping the service.