# Control Flow Exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting the following exception in the server application. What could be the reason for the issue and how can I debug the issue. I am getting the exception from different points of the thread

```
ICC_SequenceService_SequenceReportService.NotifyEventRecived]-Exception Occured :The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.-
Server stack trace: 

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The communication object cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722857/the-communication-object-cannot-be-used-for-communication-because-it-has-been-abo)

Comment: See also http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/26/dont-wrap-wcf-service-hosts-or-clients-in-a-using-statement/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because your client don't abort the channel when it is failed and try to Close it instead.  That's unfortunately the default behavior if you are using a client proxy generated by wsdl.exe and a using statement.